# "Access right" vs "Access rights"

Tags: singular-vs-plural

I'm writing the user documentation for a software. This software allows to define several access rights to data (say "read", "write" and "manage"). In this context, I sometime use the form "access right" when talking about a specific right for instance in description like this:

> - Read: this access right allows to...
> - Write: this access right allows to...
> - Manage: this access right allows to...

Is this correct in this context or should I always use "access rights" (as my boss recommends) ?

Comment: [An access right is the right to perform a particular operation on the object. For example, the FILE_READ_DATA access right specifies the right to read from a file.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/kernel/access-rights) The singular is perfectly acceptable and widely used in documentation. Why does your boss think otherwise? You can also just use "right" without "access" : https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/file-access-rights-constants

Comment: Aside: for a software *product*, or for *some* software.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, they are greatly appreciated. As for my boss' opinion, I don't think there was a good reason, just a gut feeling (he was not sure either).

Answer (score 1):

I think your choice is better. If you use "access rights", you'll have to use "these access rights", and since you are talking about a specific right in each case, that doesn't fit well.

"Allows" should probably be followed by a gerund (-ing form), rather than an infinitive ("to X").